# Setting Content Disposition and Content Type in AWS SDK (golang) has no effect

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

The title says most of it. 
I have the following code:

```
        copySource := bucket + "/" + sourcePath + "/" + filenameIn
        destPath := lambdaParams.DestinationPath + "/" + filenameIn
        copyObjectInput := s3.CopyObjectInput{
                CopySource: aws.String(copySource),
                Bucket:     aws.String(bucket),
                Key:        aws.String(destPath),
        }

            if filepath.Ext(filenameIn) == ".pdf" {
copyObjectInput.SetContentType("application/pdf").SetContentDisposition("inline; filename=\"" + filenameIn + "\"")
            }

            _, err := svc.CopyObject(&copyObjectInput)
            if err != nil {
                    logErrorAndInformGFS(err, "S3 copy error.", c, log, filenameIn)
                    return err
            }
```

I am setting both the `Content-Type` and the `Content-Disposition` with the hope of having the copied object have the new values from `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition`. However, I can see in AWS that the copied file has the same metadata as the original file. What am I leaving out?

Comment: Try a pointer to s3.CopyObjectInput, `copyObjectInput := &s3.CopyObjectInput{}`

Comment: That was a good suggestion, I don't know it even compiled as a object rather than reference. However, it still wasn't enough to modify the metadata.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the issue was that I needed to tell AWS I wanted to `REPLACE` the metadata. Adding the following line finally allowed me to change the metadata:

```
copyObjectInput.SetMetadataDirective("REPLACE")
```

Comment: This is what stackoverflow is about, thanks for taking the time to document this @SearcherMain

Comment: This just saved me about 5 hours and my fist from going through my monitor.